# CSS Button Animation

Tags: css

I am having some trouble with the direction of this css animation. I want the button to shrink and change colors when the user hovers over it. 
However when I hover over the button it just shrinks toward the upper left. Any help would be appreciated. 
Here is my **CSS code**:

```
.btn-lg {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        vertical-align: middle;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        background-color: #f04e45;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 30px;
        padding: 0.9em 2em;
        margin-top: 1em;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }

.btn-lg:hover {
        color: #f04e45;
        border-color: #f04e45;
        border-radius: 22px;
        padding: .5em 1.2em;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid ;
        transform:scale(.9);
        -webkit-transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -0-transition: all o.4s ease-in-out;
    }
```

Comment: post your relevant html too.

Comment: And/or add a jsFiddle/CodePen.

Comment: @Justin Erickson, if any of the below answers fixed your problem please mark the one you feel best meets your needs as the answer

Answer (score 1):

You could try using transform-origin (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

```
transform-origin: 100% 100%;
```

not sure if this is the effect you want but here is a code pen to see

http://codepen.io/leighquince/pen/xujhs

Oh i should also say that using this method you can control the direction however you want the first number represents x-offset and can be be px, % or the words left/right/center the second is the y offset and can again be px, % or the words top/bottom/center. This way you could state what ever direction you wanted it to shrink in.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by adding margin to the hover state of button.

```
    margin: 0.4em 0.8em;
    margin-top: 1em;
```

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/juoHb

Answer (score 0):

Add a `margin-left:15px;` to your `:hover` class. The element keeps the same box model otherwise, which keeps it aligned left.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `padding: .5em 1.2em;` from your CSS and use `transform: scale(0.9,0.9);` instead of `transform:scale(.9);`
Here is the  [Demo](http://jsbin.com/quqeleke/1/)